# I want to integrate an event listener into this code

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Basically, I'm creating a server logic that will initially check to see if a user's commit to the server is already up-to-date.

This is what I currently have:

```
var request = require("request");
var serversha1;

request("[URL REDACTED]", function(error, response, body) {
  serversha1 = body;
  console.log("Server sha1 is " + body);
  if (serversha1 == filesha1) {
    console.log("File sha1 is " + filesha1);
    console.log("The files on the server are up to date.");
  } else {
    console.log("File sha1 is " + filesha1);
    console.log("The files aren't up to date.");
  };
});

var FileHasher = require("./modules/FileHasher");
var filesha1 = FileHasher(process.argv[2]);
```

FileHasher is a function that takes in the file name and file content and hashes it, then returns the hash.

I want to change this so that the code starts running when an event "commit" is activated. "Commit" will probably have to be a custom event if I my small understanding of events and listeners is correct. Once this code hears "commit" it should start running, but not before that. I'm fairly new to node.js, so I'd really appreciate help with this.

Comment: Where does this event come from?

Comment: Events in node are pretty well documented http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.7/api/events.html.  Can you be a bit more specific with your question?

Comment: Thanks for the link! Basically I'm creating a dropbox-esque file sync system. What this code is supposed to do is that once a user clicks the commit option on the desktop GUI, this code is supposed to understand the GUI has been clicked and then check the sha1 of the file(s) that the user is pushing against the sha1 of what's already on the server. Therefore, this code must wait until  the user activates the event "push", then runs the code. I'm trying to implement this via event listeners.

Comment: Hey Brad, sorry I missed your comment! This event should be triggered by the user pressing the "commit" button in a separate GUI (that's the final stage). For now I'd like to be able to trip the event through command line on Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was pretty simple - I just used event listeners, then switched it out to run on button presses when I added in the GUI.